# Webiste url are not routing without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I uploaded my website from my UAT/Test domain to EC2 AWS. Before everything was fine, but now only home page opens.

And if I try to navigate to any other links I can't, it gives following error

The requested URL `/page/company` was not found on this server.

But when I insert `index.php` in between it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it some php framework like wordpress?

Comment: sounds like rewrites not enabled, pos dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: yes It was.
Thanks a lot for reverting quicker.
precisely i changed below line in etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 

AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable mod_rewrite module in your server and rewrite  index.php in htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, it solved the issue ..
precisely i changed below line in etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 

AllowOverride All

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file premissions

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue could be DirectoryIndex which apache (not positive that is what you are using as web server) uses to direct the user to a specific file if a directory is selected in the URL.

This can be set in your apache config if you have access, or in a .htaccess file if you only have access to the your webspace itself.

http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

Basically with DirectoryIndex you can tell apache to automatically use index.php, or index.html, or really whatever file you want to be used when no file in a directory is given in the URL.